# SQL LINQ Convert to String

Tags: c#, linq, tostring

How do I convert a dateTime SQL to a string that can be formatted?  I have not found a way to convert "requestIniationDate" to a string that can be formatted.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //"data" is a database connection through the Data folder, containing the tables
    var data = new Data.AcademicCodeRequestDBEntities();

    var request = data.Requests.Select(x => new 
                        {
                            x.appName, 
                            x.requestIniatiationDate, 
                            x.status, 
                            x.id
                        }).ToList()
                        .Select(x => new Models.RequestIdentifier() 
                        {
                            id = x.id,
                            appName = x.appName,
                            requestIniatiationDate = x.requestIniatiationDate,
                            status = x.status,

                        });
    editGrid.DataSource = request;
    editGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What type is `requestIniatiationDate` and what type is `x.requestIniatiationDate`?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `ToList()` in the middle of your LINQ query?

Comment: @maccettura requestInitationDate are datimes.  I call .ToList in order to display the items in a table format.

Comment: Your `.ToList()` call is making the result of the first select a list, but then you call `.Select()` again which turns it right back into an `IEnumerable`.  Honestly your entire LINQ statement makes little sense, just do the one `Select()` statement and end with a `.ToList()` if you need to materialize it.  Also, if both things are `DateTime` how do you expect to assign a string to a DateTime?

Comment: @maccettura I am new to LINQ and was advised to write the statement that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, `requestIniatiationDate` and `x.requestIniatiationDate` are *both* `DateTime`.  This is the source of your problem as you cannot assign a `string` to a `DateTime`.

A `DateTime` has no concept of a "format".  If you want to display your dates on a page in a specific format you need to use a string to display it.  So you need to either modify your `RequestIdentifier` model to use a string instead of DateTime, or depending on how this is being displayed on the front end you can use a property of the control.  For example, if you are using an `<asp:boundfield>` you can do this:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="requestIniatiationDate" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Obviously replace with whatever date format you need (you haven't specified).

Besides that, your Linq statement makes very little sense.  You materialize a list, then subsequently `.Select()` on it..  You select into an anonymous object first for no reason, its all very confusing.  You should be able to just do this:

```
var request = data.Requests.Select(x => new Models.RequestIdentifier() 
                    {
                        id = x.id,
                        appName = x.appName,
                        requestIniatiationDate = x.requestIniatiationDate,
                        status = x.status,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I will apply your code and let you know the result.

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 my code wont fix the DateTime problem, since that cannot be fixed.  You simply cannot directly assign a `string` to a `DateTime`.  You need to tell us exactly what you want to do with formatting because what you are trying to do is impossible

Comment: the request date posts on my webform in the format 7/2/2018 12:00:00 AM.  The date was correct for that entry, but the time is incorrect.  How do I post the correct time or remove the time portion?

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 How are you displaying this in the webform?  What control are you using?  Add that information to your question.

Comment: I am posting the information in an asp:BoundFiled tag and the date is in the enclosed DateField.

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 ok check the edit of my answer.  You just need to change the `dataFormatString` attribute to whatever format you want

Comment: I missed that edit and it was the correct answer.  What does the "0" represent?

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 I believe its the index of the argument.  So it _should_ only ever be 0. You can check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) for more examples of formats and more info on the property

Comment: Thank you for your help and assistance on providing the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `.ToString("d")`? See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var data = new Data.AcademicCodeRequestDBEntities();
    var request = data.Requests.Select(x => new 
                    {
                        x.appName, 
                        x.requestIniatiationDate.ToString("d"), 
                        x.status, 
                        x.id
                    }).ToList()
                    .Select(x => new Models.RequestIdentifier() 
                    {
                        id = x.id,
                        appName = x.appName,
                        requestIniatiationDate = x.requestIniatiationDate.ToString("d"),
                        status = x.status,
                    });
    editGrid.DataSource = request;
    editGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: When I try the .ToString() I get an error -> can not convert string to System.DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that requestIniatiationDate is a string, you can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //"data" is a database connection through the Data folder, containing the tables
    var data = new Data.AcademicCodeRequestDBEntities();

    var request = data.Requests.Select(x => new 
                        {
                            x.appName, 
                            x.requestIniatiationDate, 
                            x.status, 
                            x.id
                        }).ToList()
                        .Select(x => new Models.RequestIdentifier() 
                        {
                            id = x.id,
                            appName = x.appName,
                            requestIniatiationDate = x.requestIniatiationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), //change to the format you want
                            status = x.status,

                        });
    editGrid.DataSource = request;
    editGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: when I add .ToString I get an error -> Returns the text representation of the value of the current Nullable<T> object. No overload for method "ToString' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: It might be due to requestIniatiationDate being null. In those cases you can decide what to print by filtering them first or doing an iif on the select.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming reqiestInitiationDate is DateTime and you want the format yyyy-MM-dd

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    var data = new Data.AcademicCodeRequestDBEntities();    
    var request = data.Requests
                        .Select(x => new Models.RequestIdentifier() 
                        {
                            id = x.id,
                            appName = x.appName,
                            requestIniatiationDate = x.requestIniatiationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            status = x.status,    
                        }).ToList();
    editGrid.DataSource = request;
    editGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: All the requestIniationDate is a nullable datetime.  Should I have not made that nullable?

Comment: If it's nullable, you'll need something like:
x.requestIniatiationDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ?? string.Empty,
That will not call ToString if the dateTime is null (the ?.), and will substitute an empty string  (instead of the formatted string) if the datetime it null (the ??)

Comment: @ALL 
Thank you for your assistance, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```